# Why does Blender Game Engine sometimes not render texture?

Tags: rendering, texturing, game-engine

In Blender 2.79 RC1, I have several scenes. With viewport set to show texture, I start the game in standalone player. If I start the game from certain scenes, it shows textures as expected. If I start the game from one scene in particular, however, it loads as if in solid mode. Why does this vary from scene to scene? Are there any other settings relevant to how BGE renders scenes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I had set the scene that was loading differently to use GLSL shading instead of Multitexture shading.

Comment: Indeed the BGE will use the settings from the scene you start the session from.